# Flutter listen to js messages

Tags: javascript, flutter, dart, message

I have a Flutter app with a simple webvew plugin. In my login.js file I have a simple function that gives back username and password.

```
function saveUserPass(credentials){
        if (typeof Android !== 'undefined') {
            if (Android.saveValues !== 'undefined') {
                Android.saveValues(credentials.username, credentials.password);
            }
        }
    var iOS = /iPad|iPhone|iPod/.test(navigator.userAgent) && !window.MSStream;    
    if (iOS) { 
    window.webkit.messageHandlers.saveValeus.postMessage({"name": credentials.username,"pwd": credentials.password}); 
    } 
    }

}
```

Is there a way to listen to those messages in Flutter?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `javascriptChannels` property of the [`WebView` class](https://pub.dev/documentation/webview_flutter/latest/webview_flutter/WebView-class.html).

**For flutter** - You need to create a new `JavascriptChannel` and pass it to your `WebView` constructor:

```
JavascriptChannel channel = JavascriptChannel(name: 'Print', onMessageReceived: (JavascriptMessage message) { print(message.message); });

WebView(
  javascriptChannels: {channel},
  ...
)
```

The `onMessageReceived` property of the channel can be used to handle the message in any way that you need.

**For JS** - Anytime you want to send a message from JS, call the `name`(in this case "Print")`.postMessage(message)`:

```JS
Print.postMessage('Hello');
```

Comment: For me this method doesnt work, did I missed something?

Comment: This  didnt work for me either Print comes out as undefined

Comment: how to send objects? using postMessage.

Comment: Use `window` to send attribute via JS. e.g. `window.Print.postMessage('Hello')` or `window.webkit.messageHandlers.Print.postMessage('...')` where Print is optional variable name.